# Using Komodo IDE 12: Do not know how to link index.html to style.css

Tags: html, css

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPVEY.jpg)I am not sure how to link my HTML to the CSS. I know that I have to make sure that they are in the same folder but since this is my first project, I dont quite know my way around Komodo. Any help would be appreciated!

I have already added the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
```

This is what I have so far:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Copy the files to the same directory. Then open up Komodo.
- Select from the menu *project–>new project*. Select the new project
  directory.
- In Komodo on the left panel it will display the list of files.
- You can preview the index file in browser by going to *view–>browser
  view*.
- Select the default browser to view the file in Komodo side panel.
- Edit the files to see what changes.

Comment: Thank you focus.style!

Answer (score 0):

Your styles.css should be in the same folder as your html file.

I suggest you this website if you want to learn HTML and CSS:
http://www.w3schools.com/